# Function notation (domain "maps to" range) for a parameterized function

Tags: functions, notation

I have a function $f(x; a)$. Note that $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$. For simplicity, let's say the function is $f(x; a) = ax$. For my use case, it is more convenient to think about $f$ as a function of $x$ that is parameterized by $a$ (as opposed to a function of $x$ and $a$).

I'd like to express $f$ using the "maps to" function notation. My question is, is it more appropriate to express it as $f : \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ or as $f : \mathbb{R^2} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$? I can't find any examples of this notation for a function that also uses "parameterized by" notation.

My guess is the former, as $f$ is viewed as a function of one variable (that just so happens to be parameterized). However, given discussion in [Why do we say function "parameterized by" vs just function of (x,y,z,...)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1678263/why-do-we-say-function-parameterized-by-vs-just-function-of-x-y-z/1678283), there is no mathematical difference between writing $f$ as $f(x; a)$ and $f(x, a)$. However, in the latter case one would surely use the function notation $f : \mathbb{R^2} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$. This is the source of my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to consider $a$ as a parameter, then you will write that you are using a *family* of functions $(f_a)_{a\in \mathbb{R}}$ : each one of them are then defined by $f_a(x) = ax$ (so $f_a:\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ for each $a\in \mathbb{R}$).

In the other case (two variables) you will indeed write $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (a,x) \mapsto ax $.

But you cannot write simultaneously $f:\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$... (the first one is not defined).

I hope it will help a bit.

Comment: Thanks! Ideally, I would like to stick to the $f(x;a)$ notation as well (instead of introducing a family of functions), since that’s the standard in my field. I think of parameters as constants once they’re chosen, so if $a=10$, then $f(x;10) = 10x$ and that function can be described as $f : \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$.